# Java - Converting a Depth First Search program to a Breadth-First Search program (LinkedList)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

So this was a homework assignment that was due earlier this week, but I wasn't able to finish it all in time.

This is the initial "map.txt" file with all the info we needed to do this project.:

```
Washington, D.C.|Norfolk|208
Washington, D.C.|Baltimore|39
Washington, D.C.|Philadelphia|235
Washington, D.C.|Pittsburgh|251
Washington, D.C.|Charleston, W.VA|380
Washington, D.C.|Charlotte|388
Washington, D.C.|Knoxville|512
Washington, D.C.|Cincinnati|523
Washington, D.C.|Richmond|108
Norfolk|Richmond|99
Knoxville|Nashville|177
Knoxville|Charlotte|231
Knoxville|Cincinnati|254
Knoxville|Raleigh|362
Knoxville|Charleston, SC|403
Charleston, SC|Myrtle Beach|98
Charleston, SC|Savannah|108
Charleston, SC|Charlotte|218
Charleston, W.VA|Pittsburgh|221
Charleston, W.VA|Louisville|257
Charleston, W.VA|Cleveland|260
Charleston, W.VA|Charlotte|314
Charleston, W.VA|Richmond|331
Orlando|Daytona Beach|58
Orlando|Tampa|84
Orlando|Lake City|160
Orlando|Miami|236
Tallahassee|Lake City|111
Tallahassee|Montgomery|208
Tallahassee|Tampa|252
Tallahassee|Mobile|253
Tallahassee|Atlanta|275
Atlanta|Birmingham|149
Atlanta|Montgomery|161
Atlanta|Knoxville|230
Atlanta|Charlotte|249
Atlanta|Nashville|252
Atlanta|Savannah|256
Atlanta|Lake City|292
Atlanta|Charleston, SC|329
Atlanta|Jacksonville|354
Atlanta|Memphis|394
Memphis|Little Rock|138
Memphis|Nashville|208
Memphis|Jackson|212
Memphis|Birmingham|241
Memphis|Springfield|281
Memphis|St. Louis|283
Jacksonville|Raleigh|536
Jacksonville|Charlotte|399
Jacksonville|Tampa|190
Jacksonville|Savannah|138
Jacksonville|Daytona Beach|99
Jacksonville|Lake City|65
Lake City|Tampa|169
Miami|Tampa|266
Miami|Key West|156
Miami|Daytona Beach|270
Kansas City|Topeka|65
Kansas City|Springfield|170
Kansas City|Wichita|183
Kansas City|Des Moines|197
Wilmington|Norfolk|259
Wilmington|Richmond|255
Wilmington|Myrtle Beach|71
Grand Forks|Fargo|76
Grand Forks|Minot|210
Grand Forks|Duluth|268
Duluth|Madison|340
Des Moines|Madison|373
Milwaukee|Madison|78
Chicago|Milwaukee|91
Chicago|Madison|152
Chicago|Indianapolis|177
Chicago|Grand Rapids|190
Chicago|St. Louis|302
Chicago|Cleveland|345
Chicago|Des Moines|362
Chicago|Nashville|473
Chicago|Kansas City|557
Chicago|Detroit|300
Detroit|Grand Rapids|157
Detroit|Cleveland|173
Detroit|Columbus|206
Detroit|Cincinnati|260
Detroit|Indianapolis|283
Detroit|Buffalo, NY|417
Buffalo, NY|Cleveland|194
Buffalo, NY|Binghamton|220
Buffalo, NY|Albany|289
Binghamton|Albany|137
Cincinnati|Louisville|102
Cincinnati|Indianapolis|108
Cincinnati|Columbus|109
Cincinnati|Columbus|202
Cincinnati|St. Louis|353
Montgomery|Birmingham|92
Montgomery|Mobile|171
Montgomery|Jackson|251
New York City|Hartford|118
New York City|Albany|160
New York City|Harrisburg|174
New York City|Binghamton|199
New York City|Cleveland|481
New York City|Philadelphia|99
Harrisburg|Philadelphia|105
Baltimore|Philadelphia|98
Boston|Hartford|101
Boston|Portland, ME|103
Boston|Albany|177
Denver|Cheyenne|102
Denver|Lamar|206
Denver|Oakley|247
Denver|North Platte|290
Denver|Cortez|411
Denver|Albuquerque|457
Denver|Salt Lake City|529
Denver|St. George|648
Portland, ME|Bangor|132
Portland, OR|Eugene|115
Portland, OR|Seattle|180
Portland, OR|Riley|268
Portland, OR|Crescent City|346
Portland, OR|Spokane|400
Portland, OR|Boise|439
Reno|Winnamucca|164
Reno|Yosemite Village|213
Reno|Ely|331
Reno|Riley|342
Boise|Riley|210
Boise|Twin Falls|123
Boise|Winnamucca|257
Boise|Spokane|379
Boise|Seattle|499
Spokane|Seattle|276
Bismarck|Minot|106
Bismarck|Fargo|194
Bismarck|Pierre|209
Bismarck|Rapid City|358
Bismarck|Billings|418
Bismarck|Malta|430
Rapid City|Pierre|174
Rapid City|Buffalo, WY|216
Rapid City|Cheyenne|290
Rapid City|Sioux Falls|350
Phoenix|Tucson|112
Phoenix|Flagstaff|141
Phoenix|Springerville|236
Phoenix|San Diego|368
Phoenix|El Paso|404
Los Angeles|Phoenix|393
Los Angeles|San Diego|118
Los Angeles|Barstow|138
Los Angeles|Yosemite Village|313
Los Angeles|Reno|522
San Francisco|Los Angeles|384
San Francisco|Reno|228
San Francisco|Barstow|442
San Francisco|Yosemite Village|193
San Francisco|Crescent City|371
San Francisco|Eugene|540
Riley|Eugene|230
Las Vegas|St. George|122
Las Vegas|Barstow|155
Las Vegas|Ely|282
Las Vegas|Phoenix|288
Las Vegas|Reno|442
Las Vegas|Salt Lake City|423
Salt Lake City|Twin Falls|222
Salt Lake City|Rawlins|294
Salt Lake City|Ely|294
Salt Lake City|St. George|305
Salt Lake City|Cortez|348
Salt Lake City|Winnamucca|362
Salt Lake City|Helena|482
Salt Lake City|Old Faithful|482
Raleigh|Wilmington|127
Raleigh|Richmond|156
Raleigh|Norfolk|170
Cleveland|Pittsburgh|141
Cleveland|Columbus|146
Cleveland|Des Moines|677
San Antonio|Eagle Pass|142
San Antonio|Laredo|154
San Antonio|Houston|201
San Antonio|Brownsville|281
San Antonio|Big Spring|298
San Antonio|El Paso|552
San Antonio|Dallas|273
Dallas|Oklahoma City|208
Dallas|Houston|237
Dallas|Big Spring|266
Dallas|Springfield|282
Dallas|Little Rock|315
Dallas|Amarillo|367
Dallas|Jackson|417
Dallas|New Orleans|509
Omaha|Des Moines|143
Omaha|Topeka|163
Omaha|Sioux Falls|175
Omaha|Kansas City|194
Omaha|North Platte|298
Omaha|Liberal|489
Omaha|Rapid City|539
Minneapolis|Duluth|152
Minneapolis|Fargo|242
Minneapolis|Sioux Falls|247
Minneapolis|Madison|260
Minneapolis|Des Moines|286
Minneapolis|Pierre|399
Minneapolis|Omaha|409
Minneapolis|St. Louis|540
New Orleans|Mobile|153
New Orleans|Jackson|183
New Orleans|Birmingham|354
New Orleans|Houston|363
Buffalo, WY|Old Faithful|296
Buffalo, WY|Billings|168
Buffalo, WY|Rawlins|236
Old Faithful|Rawlins|320
Rawlins|Cheyenne|146
North Platte|Cheyenne|215
North Platte|Oakley|158
North Platte|Pierre|264
Charlotte|Raleigh|175
Charlotte|Myrtle Beach|180
Charlotte|Wilmington|188
Nashville|Louisville|180
Nashville|St. Louis|312
Nashville|Birmingham|192
Jackson|Birmingham|234
Pittsburgh|Harrisburg|218
Pittsburgh|Columbus|184
Indianapolis|St. Louis|244
Indianapolis|Columbus|179
Indianapolis|Louisville|124
Brownsville|Houston|365
Brownsville|Laredo|204
Eagle Pass|Laredo|124
Billings|Malta|206
Billings|Helena|243
Helena|Old Faithful|216
Helena|Malta|293
Helena|Missoula|116
Spokane|Missoula|198
Twin Falls|Missoula|401
Twin Falls|Ely|255
Little Rock|Springfield|219
Little Rock|Jackson|267
Little Rock|Houston|315
Little Rock|Oklahoma City|336
Little Rock|St. Louis|350
St. Louis|Des Moines|387
St. Louis|Louisville|259
St. Louis|Kansas City|250
St. Louis|Springfield|224
Malta|Minot|457
Fargo|Minot|268
Fargo|Duluth|259
Fargo|Sioux Falls|253
Flagstaff|St. George|286
Flagstaff|Cortez|263
Flagstaff|Barstow|348
San Diego|Barstow|181
El Paso|Big Spring|344
El Paso|Amarillo|412
El Paso|Eagle Pass|484
El Paso|Houston|746
El Paso|Tucson|324
El Paso|Albuquerque|270
Albuquerque|Lamar|393
Albuquerque|Flagstaff|325
Albuquerque|Amarillo|296
Albuquerque|Cortez|273
Albuquerque|Springerville|233
Albuquerque|Big Spring|418
Albuquerque|Liberal|421
Amarillo|Liberal|164
Amarillo|Oklahoma City|259
Amarillo|Big Spring|224
Amarillo|Lamar|228
Liberal|Lamar|168
Liberal|Oakley|143
Liberal|Wichita|209
Topeka|Wichita|138
Topeka|Oakley|289
Topeka|Liberal|361
Oklahoma City|Wichita|156
Oklahoma City|Liberal|256
Oklahoma City|Springfield|283
```

This is the java file for my "MapPoints"

```
public class MapPoint
{
    private String StartingPoint = null;
    private String EndingPoint = null;
    private int distance = 0;
    private boolean visited = false;
    private boolean backEdge = false;

    public MapPoint(String sp, String ep, int d)
    {
        StartingPoint = sp;
        EndingPoint = ep;
        distance = d;
        visited = false;
        backEdge = false;
    }

    public String getStartPoint()
    {
        return StartingPoint;
    }

    public String getEndPoint()
    {
        return EndingPoint;
    }

    public int getDistance()
    {
        return distance;
    }

    public boolean getVisit()
    {
        return visited;
    }

    public boolean getBackEdge()
    {
        return backEdge;
    }

    public void setStartPoint(String input)
    {
        StartingPoint = input;
    }

    public void setEndPoint(String input)
    {
        EndingPoint = input;
    }

    public void setDistance(int input)
    {
        distance = input;
    }

    public void setVisit(boolean b)
    {
        visited = b;
    }

    public void setBackEdge(boolean t)
    {
        backEdge = t;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "Starting point: " + getStartPoint() + "\nEnding point: " + getEndPoint() + "\nDistance: " + getDistance();
        return output;
    }

}
```

This is the java file for my "Node"

```
public class Node
{
    private MapPoint data = null;
    private Node next = null;
    private Node previous = null;
    private boolean visited = false;


    public Node(MapPoint inData, Node inNext, Node inPrev)
    {
        data = inData;
        next = inNext;
        previous = inPrev;
        visited = false;
    }

    /**
    * getNext returns what's in the next position
    * @return The next Node
    */
    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    /**
    * setNext sets the data to be stored in the next slot in the linked list
    * @param inNext The next Node
    */
    public void setNext(Node inNext)
    {
        next = inNext;
    }

    /**
    * getPrevious returns the previous Node
    * @return The previous Node
    */
    public Node getPrevious()
    {
        return previous;
    }

    /**
    * setPrevious sets the data to be stored in the previous slot in the linked list
    * @param inPrev The previous Node
    */
    public void setPrevious(Node inPrev)
    {
        previous = inPrev;
    }

    public void setVisit(boolean b)
    {
        visited = b;
    }

    public boolean getVisit()
    {
        return visited;
    }

    /**
    * getData returns the data stored in that Node
    */
    public MapPoint getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

}
```

and this is the java file for my "NodeList"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The NodeList.java class controls the order of the linked list and can add and remove data from the list
 */

public class NodeList
{
  Node head = null;

  /**
   * add adds data to the end of the linked list
   * @param
   */
  public void add(MapPoint data)
  {
    if(head == null)
      head = new Node(data, null, null);
    else
    {
      Node current  = head;
      while(current.getNext() != null)
      {
        current = current.getNext();
      }

      Node temp = new Node(data, null, current);
      current.setNext(temp);
    }
  }

  /**
   * remove removes data from the linked list and moves other data around to fill the missing data's spot
   * @param
   * @return
   */
  public MapPoint remove(MapPoint point)
  {
    Node target = search(point);

    if(target == null)// not there/no items in list
        return null;
    else// there/more items in list 
    {
      if(target == head)// first item in list
      {
        if(target.getNext() == null)// What if only one item in list?
        {
          head = null;
          return target.getData();
        }
        else// first item and more than one item in the list
        {
          target.getNext().setPrevious(null);
          head = target.getNext();
          return target.getData();
        }
      }
      else// not first item in list
      {
        target.getPrevious().setNext(target.getNext()); 

        if(target.getNext() != null)// if item is at end of list
        {
          target.getNext().setPrevious(target.getPrevious());
          return target.getData();
        }

        return target.getData();
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * search searches the linked list
   * @param point
   * @return
   */
  public Node search(MapPoint point)
  {
    Node current = head;

    while(current != null)
    {
      if(current.getData().getStartPoint().equals(point.getStartPoint()))
        return current;

      current = current.getNext();
    }

    return null;
  }

  public Node search(String sp){

      Node current = head;

      while(current != null){
          if(current.getData().getStartPoint().equals(sp))
              return current;

          current = current.getNext();
      }

      return null;
  }

 public ArrayList<MapPoint> searchAll(String sp){

     ArrayList<MapPoint> mp = new ArrayList<>();

     Node current = head;
     while(current != null){
         if(current.getData().getStartPoint().equals(sp) && current.getData().getVisit() == false)
             mp.add(current.getData());

         else if(current.getData().getEndPoint().equals(sp) && current.getData().getVisit() == false){
             current.getData().setEndPoint(current.getData().getStartPoint());
             current.getData().setStartPoint(sp);

             mp.add(current.getData());
         }

         current = current.getNext();
     }

     return mp;
 }

  /**
   * numElements counts the number of elements in the linked list
   * @return
   */
  public int numElements()
  {
    Node current = head;
    int count = 0;

    if(current == null)
      return 0;

    while(current != null)
    {
      count++;
      current = current.getNext();
    }

    return count;
  }

  /**
   * toString returns information about what is inside the NodeList
   * @return A String containing information about the contents of the NodeList
   */
  public String toString()
  {
    Node current = head;
    String output = "";
    while(current != null)
    {
      output = output + current.getData() + "\n";
      current = current.getNext();
    }

    return output;
  }
}
```

Basically, we needed to do both a Depth-First Search and a Breadth-First Search (and make an MST, but that was easier than this part).

This is my code for my driver of the program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MapDriver
{
    private static int cities = 1;
    private static int totWeight = 0;

    public static NodeList createMap()
    {

        Scanner input;
        String filename = "map.txt";

        NodeList map = new NodeList();

        try
        {
            input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            String[] values;

            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                values = input.nextLine().trim().split("\\|");
                map.add(new MapPoint(values[0], values[1], Integer.parseInt(values[2])));
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Number format exception.");
        }

        return map;

    }  

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String start = "Grand Forks";

        //Depth First Search

        System.out.println("City: " + start);
        System.out.println("Total Weight: " + totWeight);
        System.out.println("# of Cities: " + cities);
        System.out.println("");

        map = createMap();
        DFS dfs = new DFS(map);
        dfs.drive(start);

    }
}
```

And this is the code for the object I made for my DFS:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DFS
{

    private int cities = 1;
    private int totWeight = 0;
    private NodeList m;
    private ArrayList<String> cityNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public DFS(NodeList m)
    {

        this.m = m;

    }

    public void drive(String start)
    {

        cityNames.add(start);

        ArrayList<MapPoint> mp = m.searchAll(start);

        for(int i = 0; i < mp.size(); i++)
        {
            if(mp.get(i).getVisit() == false && mp.get(i).getBackEdge() == false && !cityNames.contains(mp.get(i).getEndPoint()))
            {
                mp.get(i).setVisit(true);
                mp.get(i).setBackEdge(true);

                String search = mp.get(i).getEndPoint();
                System.out.println("City: " + search);

                totWeight = totWeight + mp.get(i).getDistance();
                System.out.println("Total Weight: " + totWeight);

                cities = cities + 1;
                System.out.println("# of Cities: " + cities);

                System.out.println("");

                drive(search);
            }

        }        

    }

}
```

Is there any easy way I could've converted my DFS.java into a working Breadth-First Search of the NodeList, where it would hit all 114 cities? I wasn't able to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Sorry, not gonna click on your links. You should copy/paste your code here if you want help here...

Comment: Ok, I just thought that'd be a little easier, but I can do that for sure!

Comment: Okay, first step is done. Now, what have you tried? And how doesn't that work?